# JavaScript not working in WKWebView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, swift4

I am new to iOS and loading my website developed in **jQuery Mobile** to a `WKWebView` in Swift 4 and Xcode 9. After loading it inside a controller, I noticed that JavaScript is not called on some pages (for example, buttons that open the dialer to call and social sharing buttons don't work).

My code for loading the page:

```
let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.mySiteUrl.com")
let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
webView.load(myRequest)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that the JS scripts are from a non-HTTPS source and you left **App Transport Security**'s **Allow Arbitrary Loads** disabled.

Here is how to fix that:

1. Navigate to **Project Settings/Target/[your app's target]/Info**.

[image: screenshot of Project Settings]

2. Check whether there is a dictionary called **App Transport Security Settings**. If not, create it.
3. Inside it, create a boolean value called **Allow Arbitrary Loads** (if it's not there yet) and set it to **YES**.

[image: App Transport Security Settings/Allow Arbitrary Loads with the value YES]

Comment: I think it may be the issue as some of the redirect links are http:// instead of https